# How to stretch a QLineEdit Box to fit the whole Tab screen?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Code:

```
class Tab(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        TabButton = QPushButton()
        TabButton.setText("+")
        TabButton.clicked.connect(self.getTabName)
        self.setCornerWidget(TabButton)
        tabBar = TabBar(self)
        self.setTabBar(tabBar)
        tablayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.ProgressBox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.ProgressSize = QSizePolicy()
        ProgressBox2 = QLineEdit(self)
        ProgressBox3 = QLineEdit(self)
        tablayout.addWidget(self.ProgressBox, 1)
        tablayout.addWidget(ProgressBox2, 1)
        tablayout.addWidget(ProgressBox3, 1)
        self.setLayout(tablayout)
```

I have put the QLineEdit inside a Horizontal Layout, inside a Tab, I want to stretch the QLineEdit Vertically so it fills up the empty spaces

I tried using setfixedHeight but the Box will go through the tab, and some other methods wont work.
[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. You talk about "screen", but you probably mean "window". Then you say that you want to "stretch it" (what? the line edit? which one?) to fill the whole screen (width?), and then you say that it should actually fit 1/3. Finally, you're talking about height, which doesn't make a lot of sense given what you asked before. Please try to be more clear.

Comment: @musicamante what I meant is I want the QLineEdit to stretch vertically to fill in the empty spaces in the tab

Comment: See [QSizePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html) and the [`sizePolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) property: `self.ProgressBox.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)`. But, be aware, using an expanding vertical policy for a line edit is definitely *not* a good idea, UX wise. Also, only classes and constants should have capitalized names, so you should use `self.progressBox`, `tabButton`, `progressBox2` and `progressBox3`. Read the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)